# Replicating Standard chatter publisher action in Visualforce global action

Tags: visualforce, chatter, publisher-action

I have a requirement were if a user posts a chatter message to followers (ie not in a group or from a record) it warns the user that they are posting this to potentially everyone in the org (it will appear in global search etc).

So I created a VisualForce global action and I can detect if they are on a record/group etc but is there a way of displaying the chatter publisher box without totally re-creating it in Visualforce?

EG:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the end this was not possible without totally rebuilding the text input with our own chatter action. What we did was added a trigger on the chatter objects so that if someone posted a message without including a hashtag #Public it would throw and error saying that "This post is potentially visible by anyone in the org. Please add #Public to your post to show you accept this". Solved :)